# how to update user setting in VSCode, latest version doesn't show text view for settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

I need to do changes as per screen shot below

[image]

but latest version of VS Code 1.37.1 doesn't have the text view to do changes as below

[image]

How to do changes in this case ? I need to change setting related to prettier extension

Comment: have you tried- 'Try our new Preview editor' just above the search setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the middle icon in top right corner to access settings.json.

[image]